# Wordpress localhost doesn't show front-end

Tags: macos, wordpress, localhost, frontend, bitnami

Can't see the front end of my wordpress localhost.

The process I've done:
1. I installed wordpress locally with BitNami on Mac OX. 
2. imported an existing data base to the phpmyadmin.
3. changed the wp-config file to support the local host database.
4. added these two lines
`define('WP_HOME','http://localhost/wordpress');` 
`define('WP_SITEURL','http://localhost/wordpress');` 
5. logged in to my wp-admin. 

Now I can see the site's WP-ADMIN and do things in it BUT I cannot view the front end.
whenever I try i get:
can't establish a connection to the server at 127.0.0.1.

or if i try to view a post i get 
"The requested URL /site/2013/02/13/idho_global/ was not found on this server."

If I'm trying to preview a draft I see it the way it should appear.

any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the database via phpmydmin and change the url if you didn't do it.
In the `wp_options` check if `siteurl` & home are set to `localhost`

Update : you should have a look to the 'Moving Wordpress page' https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress
It explains very well ho to change permalinks and things to do after moving a Wordpress.

If your permalinks don't works, check if you have a `.htaccess` in the root directory. The content should be :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: X4viet thank you! That solved one problem. Now it displays the site but not the posts / pages. So I still get the 404 error whenever I click on anything. The requested URL /idho2/2013/02/13/idho_global/ was not found on this server.

Comment: Just noticed that upon chancing the premlinks to default it works. but when i revert them back to 'month and name' they don't.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the database urls. Wordpress hardcodes them. Run the sql below replacing "old-url.com/wordpress" and "new-url.com/wordpress" with your urls

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = REPLACE(guid, 'old-url.com/wordpress', 'new-url.com/wordpress');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'old-url.com/wordpress', 'new-url.com/wordpress');
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = REPLACE(option_value, 'old-url.com/wordpress', 'new-url.com/wordpress');
```

Comment: it wasn't this thing. i've already changed all the addresses in advance. tnx anyway.